Do things that always existed require less explanation than things that begin to exist?
This came up from a recent discussion I was having with Conifold where I started wondering: do facts about reality that don’t seem to “start” and just potentially always existed (such as the “beginning” of the universe; why there is something rather than nothing) require less of an explanation than something that “starts” to exist like why a particle was detected here rather than there in quantum mechanics?
Now there are two modes in which I wanted to ask this:
1.) Is there anything apriori that suggests that one kind of thing requires more of an explanation than the other? (I.e. things that start to exist vs. things that always did)
2.) What does the evidence about the world tell us?
Is there anything in the philosophical literature that can be pointed to that deals with this question?

"facts about reality that don’t seem to “start” and just potentially always existed, such as the “beginning” of the universe;" in what sense the "beginning" of universe always existed? It seems a process, a change and not a "static" object.

Regarding the explanation of "change", see at least Aristotle: every change needs a cause.

Well usually a start requires a before. But the universe may not have a before

I think that a start definitely requires a before, by definition.  So for an object to come into existence we might ask how it came into existence, but for an object that has always existed we might ask how it has always existed.  I don’t believe we have the answer to either, but I don’t see one as more problematic than the other.

@Frog where do the non-negative integers start? is there a anything before 0 in the set of non-negative integers? Or do you make a distinction between "start" and "begin" or "first"?

See: https://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/5312/1/BeginningOfTime.pdf

It's merely intuitive that a start requires a before.  This is not necessarily true.  Intuitions about things far divorced from our experience should be doubted.  The arguments that deal with things "that begin to exist" are intuitive thought experiments from almost a thousand years ago.  We should treat their intuitions about the beginnings of the universe with as much respect as we do their medical intuitions from the same period.

What on Earth does ‘more’ explanation mean?

@Frog, "I think that a start definitely requires a before, by definition." Except if time itself started at the big bang, how do you define or describe the state of affairs prior to the big bang if the concept of before wasn't even possible?

@Michael Hall I agree that if there’s no way to measure time then the concept of time is meaningless.  In that sense there’s no way to say ‘for how long was there nothing’ but I believe it is still valid to say that there was nothing before there was something.

You'll get mixed answers from the philosophy literature (big surprise ;-).
A great place to start is the Principle of Sufficient Reason which deals with what demands an explanation. However, it also has a hard time "ending" the infinite regress of reasons in an elegant way.
I'd say the biggest divide is between necessary truths and contingent truths in a metaphysical theory.
Necessary truths are true in every possible world and do not need an explanation. They are the starting points of the theory. Contingent truths must be explained in terms of other contingent truths and/or necessary truths.
So if we interpret "always existed" as "necessarily true" then yes, you need zero explanation (otherwise its contingent on whatever is in your explanation :)
A good example is this:
Naturalism takes as necessary truths:

The conditions at the beginning of the universe (T=0)

"Standard monotheism" takes as necessary truths:

There is an eternal omnipotent, omniscient, omnibenevolent being "God"
This being is the cause of the initial state of the universe at T=0

As metaphysical theories, both of these are perfectly fine. Where we get to arguments is about whether "God" as a reason for the initial conditions is a better necessary condition than simply stating the initial conditions as necessary.
In both cases, we are referring to things that "always existed" or are "necessary" but many people feel that positing an intelligence behind the universe is more satisfying and "complete" than just saying "for all we know right now, the initial conditions are necessary for everything we see around us."
I'm not going there for this post, but your question reminded me of this example.

OP: 1.) Is there anything apriori that suggests that one kind of thing requires more of an explanation than the other? (I.e. things that start to exist vs. things that always did)
Let's start with where things begin.
With respect to cogito ergo sum, "I think therefore I am", the "I" is a priori, and is a form of being.
(That is to say Dasein, from the point of view of the experiencer, is being.)
The judgements of the cogito bring things into objective existence, e.g. Kant's note 36 B287 :

"[existence] is the conjunction of the [notional] thing with perception."

So in observations of the cosmos one distinguishes (classifies matter as) planets, stars, nebulae, and one might speculate on their material origin.  In speculating on the collective origin of all matter one simply runs out of information.  The ultimate cause is unknown, although we can know logically that the origin of matter cannot be more matter.  Knowlege of the cosmos is a posteriori, drawn from experience.
The a priori cogito, as previously mentioned is a form of being, and, further to Pascal's observation in The Geometrical Spirit

We cannot undertake to define being without falling into [an]
absurdity: for we cannot define a word without beginning with the word
"it is", either expressed or understood. To define being therefore, it
is necessary to say "it is", and thus to employ the word defined in
the definition.

And so we have in Being & Time (GA 2, H. 4)

"Being" cannot be derived from higher concepts by definition, nor can
it be presented through lower ones. ... [therefore] We can infer only that 'Being'
cannot have the character of an entity.

(The inference is also supported by the fact that the origin of beings cannot be a being/thing/entity.  Entities cannot altogether originate from entities otherwise their cause would be an entity, which is what's cause is sought.)
So being is not a being; it is not a thing.  The principle of sufficient reason says every thing must have a reason or cause.  So this leaves being without reason or cause.  Free to be.
This does leave the 'reality' 'outside' experience unaddressed and unknown.  But since it cannot be brought into objective existence it cannot be rationalised, explained or attributed reason or cause.
To conclude, recapping the OP questions:-

1.) Is there anything apriori that suggests that one kind of thing requires more of an explanation than the other? (I.e. things that
start to exist vs. things that always did)
2.) What does the evidence about the world tell us?


The a priori does not have/require cause or reason.

Evidence of the world is too limited to explain the reason or cause   of everything.



The word "require" is doing all the heavy lifting in your question.  I am not sure it is the correct word.
The difference between necessary starting conditions and things that can be observed to be caused by other things is our ability and access, understand or formulate an explanation rather than a requirement for one.
We may find ourselves needing to "start somewhere" but that is more so based upon our ability to explain things or imagine them different, which makes the "requirement" of an explanation based on our own viewpoint or limitations and thus is subjective.

I propose to interpret your opening question as:  Do things that exist at all times t <= t1, where t1 is any time the thing exists, require less explanation than other things?
"What does the evidence about the world tell us?"  (I will only address this mode of the question, since a priori approaches to the question strike me as barren.)  The general theory of relativity allows for spacetimes that have an earliest time.  Some of those spacetimes also have a latest time, but our universe fits reasonably well to a relativistic spacetime with an earliest time and no latest time.  However, relativity and quantum mechanics are widely regarded among physicists as conflicting, or at least hard to reconcile, and there are respectable (yet speculative) proposals that would allow for times prior to the Big Bang.
Both the general theory of relativity, and some interpretations of quantum mechanics, are bi-directionally (in time) "deterministic".  By "deterministic" I just mean that from the mathematical description of the state of the universe at one time, plus the laws of physics, you can derive the state at another time.  This means that the entire history of the universe can be explained by describing the laws and then picking any time, not necessarily the first, and describing that time in complete detail.  (I'm ignoring details about the "foliation" of spacetime.)  So perhaps your question builds-in a prejudice that you should be wary of.

Yes, things that always existed (usually) require less explanation than things that had a beginning. This is because it is (usually) simpler and more concise to not specify any beginning. The specification of a particular start time is an extra thing we might be wrong about.
Suppose we have some data that we are trying to model using a function f of a real numbered argument. It is simpler to have a model of f(x) = 1.4 everywhere, than to have f(x) = 1.4 for x > 0.2, and f(x) undefined otherwise. Because in the latter case, we specify not only the value of the function (1.4), but also the endpoint (0.2), where f begins being defined. Specifying two things means we're about twice as likely to be wrong a priori, so we'd need twice as much evidence/data to justify it.
However, this only holds usually. Some functions might be naturally only defined on a certain domain. Consider the function f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2). f(x) is real-valued for x in [-1, 1]. But it's complex-valued for x outside of that. So if we're interested only in the real values of f(x), then it is natural to say that f "begins" at -1. It would add extra complexity to define f on values below -1. For instance, to say f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2) for x in [-1, 1], f(x) = 1 for x < -1, would be more complex and require more justification than just to say that f(x) = sqrt(1 - x^2) for x in [-1, 1].

All of this is irrelevant if an actual infinity in the past is impossible, and there are many arguments to suggest that it might be. Math doesn’t apply here since a potential infinity is not the same as an actual infinity. What we’re really interested in is the latter
